# Ошибка загрузки ImageView из хранилища | Glide

Tags: java, android, imageview, glide

Используя Glide по закрытию формы пытаюсь сохранить ImageView и путьк нему в файл. А при запуске считать путь , а потом картинку по этому пути. Код:

```
private ImageView profileImage;
        private MainActivity mainActivity;
        private String pathImage;
        protected ArrayList<CountingEntry> countingEntries;
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mainActivity = this;
            countingEntries = new ArrayList<CountingEntry>();
            countingEntries.add(new CountingEntry("Coca Cola",300,LocalDate.now()));
            countingEntries.add(new CountingEntry("Pepsi",500,LocalDate.now()));
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            profileImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_Image);
            LoadAvatarImagePath();
            if(pathImage == null)
            {
                profileImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.emptyavatar);
            }
            profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent gallery = new Intent();
                    gallery.setType("image/*");
                    gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery,"Sellect Picture"), 1);
                }
            });
            RefreshList();
        }
    
        private void LoadAvatarImagePath()
        {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = sharedPreferences.getString("SavedImagePath",null);
            if(!json.isEmpty())
            {
                Type type = new TypeToken<String>() {}.getType();
                pathImage = gson.fromJson(json, type);
                RefreshList();
            }
            Glide.with(this).load(pathImage).into(profileImage);
        }
    
        private void SaveAvatarImagePath(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + "FILE_NAME" + ".jpg";
            File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/DataFolder");
            boolean success = true;
            if (!storageDir.exists())
            {
                success = storageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            if (success)
            {
                File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
                pathImage = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
                try
                {
                    OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
                    fOut.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(pathImage);
                editor.putString("SaveImagePath", json);
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed()
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Thanks for using application!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try
            {
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)
                profileImage.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                SaveAvatarImagePath(bitmap);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();
            return;
        }
```

Но получаю ошибку. Как исправить?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.personalaccounting, PID: 19963
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.personalaccounting/com.example.personalaccounting.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3311)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3460)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2047)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.personalaccounting.MainActivity.LoadAvatarImagePath(MainActivity.java:91)
        at com.example.personalaccounting.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3460) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2047) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19963 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не полностью код выложили или у вас изначально не юзаются методы. При вызове метода:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery,"Sellect Picture"), 1);
```

у вас должен быть метод который обработает выбор файла или другую работу с интентом:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        //TODO: action
    }
}
```

дальше уже внутри этого метода и условия вы можете засетить картинку в ваш виджет и сохранить путь к ней [типа так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309190/android-pick-images-from-gallery):

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("SaveImagePath", picturePath);
editor.apply();
```

и вам не нужно будет отслеживать нажатий на кнопку назад и смотреть есть ли картинка в виджете. Не очень понятно зачем использовать gson чтобы сохранить просто строку в памяти. Вам дальше просто нужно будет при старте активности проверять наличие ключа в префах и что сохраненный там путь не пустой:

```
if(sharedPreferences.getString("SaveImagePath", "").length() != 0){
// грузить картинку по пути в виджет
}
```

по логике как-то так должно наверное быть правильнее.

Answer (score 0):

```
 **Написал такой код, но фотографию не подгружает при старте приложения**

package com.example.personalaccounting;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    
    private ImageView profileImage;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private String pathImage = "";
    protected ArrayList<CountingEntry> countingEntries;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mainActivity = this;
        countingEntries = new ArrayList<CountingEntry>();
        countingEntries.add(new CountingEntry("Coca Cola",300,LocalDate.now()));
        countingEntries.add(new CountingEntry("Pepsi",500,LocalDate.now()));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        profileImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_Image);
        profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent gallery = new Intent();
                gallery.setType("image/*");
                gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery,"Sellect Picture"), 1);
            }
        });
        LoadAvatarImagePath();
        RefreshList();
    }

    private boolean LoadAvatarImagePath()
    {
        try
        {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferencesForProfileImage", MODE_PRIVATE);
            if(sharedPreferences.getString("SavedImagePath",null).length() > 0)
            {
                pathImage = sharedPreferences.getString("SavedImagePath","defaultvalue");
                Glide.with(this).load(Uri.fromFile(new File(pathImage))).apply(new RequestOptions().override(100, 100)).into(profileImage);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        try
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Thanks for using application!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finish();
        return;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1)
        {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            try
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                pathImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH;
                profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferencesForProfileImage", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("SaveImagePath", pathImage);
                editor.apply();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 2)
        {
            CountingEntry countingEntry;
            countingEntry = (CountingEntry) data.getParcelableExtra("CountingEntry");
            countingEntries.add(countingEntry);
            RefreshList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    protected void RefreshList()
    {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerList);
        CountingEntry_Adapter countingEntry_adapter = new CountingEntry_Adapter(mainActivity, countingEntries);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(countingEntry_adapter);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_Add)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_AddNewCountingEntry.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,2);
            return true;
        }
        if(id == R.id.action_RefreshRecyclerView)
        {
            RefreshList();
            return true;
        }
        if(id == R.id.action_ClearAllCountingEntries)
        {
            countingEntries.clear();
            RefreshList();
        }
        if(id == R.id.action_SaveCountingEntries)
        {
            if(!countingEntries.isEmpty())
            {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferencesForArrayList<CountingEntries>", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(countingEntries);
                editor.putString("MyCountingEntries", json);
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Облікові записи успішно збережено!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Відсутні облікові записи для збереження!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if(id == R.id.action_LoadCountingEntries)
        {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferencesForArrayList<CountingEntries>", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = sharedPreferences.getString("MyCountingEntries",null);
            if(!json.isEmpty())
            {
                Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CountingEntry>>() {}.getType();
                countingEntries.clear();
                countingEntries = gson.fromJson(json, type);
                RefreshList();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Відсутні облікові записи для завантаження!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```